# Javascript, callback when object's attributes change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Functions in javascript are objects:

```
var x = function(){};
x.y = 1;
console.log(x.y); //Prints 1
```

Is there any way to call a function when y changes?

My reason for doing this is that I'm trying to override jquery's "$" function so that I can benchmark performance. It works fine when the JS runs `$('mySelector')`. However, plugins that are created using `$.fn.myPlugin` will change the attributes in the object I overrided, rather than the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I settled on used bandi's **defineGetter** suggestion, but looped through the attributes of the original object.

```
getAttr = function(att) {
    return function() { return eval("originalObject."+att) };
}
//Delegate all attribute access to original object
for (var att in originalObject) {
    overRiddenObject.__defineGetter__(att.toString(), getAttr(att));
}
```

And here is the full snippet that I can stick in my code to profile jQuery selectors:

```
var original$ = $;
$ = function() {
    //Ignore document.ready function calls
    if (typeof(arguments)[0] === 'function') {
        return original$.apply( this, arguments );
    }

    t1 = new  Date().getTime(); 
    // Run each selector 100 times since we can only time it to the millisecond
    for (var i=0; i<100; i++)
        x = original$.apply( this, arguments );
    t = new Date().getTime()-t1;
    // Print selector name, time taken and number of elements matched
    console.log(arguments," "+t+"ms"+" ("+x.length+" element(s))");
    return x;
};
getAttr = function(att) {
    return function() { return eval("original$."+att) };
}
//Delegate all attribute access to original object
for (var att in original$) {
    $.__defineGetter__(att.toString(), getAttr(att));
}
```

It could probably be done with better style using closure's, but it works.

Also it will only work on jQuery plugins when you remove the "$" from `(function($) {...))(jQUery)`.

This could be worked around by rewriting this to use .extend and override methods that are called during selection - something I'm looking into to make this pluggable.

Comment: Eval is evil, you can use original$[attr] instead. Also __defineGetter__ is now deprecated, use Object.defineProperty instead and use performance.now() instead of new Date().getTime()

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for are *[JavaScript setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_Getters_and_Setters)*. Be careful to study browser support tough.

The following example is from the MDN documentation. First, when you create your own objects:

```
var o = {a: 7,
         get b() {return this.a + 1;},
         set c(x) {this.a = x / 2}};
```

Second, when you augment an existing prototype:

```
var d = Date.prototype;
d.__defineGetter__("year", function() { return this.getFullYear(); });
d.__defineSetter__("year", function(y) { this.setFullYear(y); });
```

Comment: Hmmm not quite, that will only allow me to hook properties by name, I need to delegate all of them to the original object

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this that will work in all browsers. Getters and setters are nice, but are completely useless when you have to support IE6 or IE7.